# Algorithm for testing EEPRM

Tags: flash, eeprom

What are the steps or the algorithms to verify that an EEPROM is working ?

Right now I just write 10 bytes and I read 10 bytes from 10 addresses, and that's naïve approach. Is there an algorithm or an approach to verify that the eeprom is correct ?   or also the problem for flash memory testing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an initial test, you could use the [walking ones](http://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/walking-ones-and-walking-zeros-algorithm.6808/) approach.

Your flash may or may not require a [complete buffer](http://www.microchip.com/forums/m752044.aspx) to be written.

The walking ones test is well known and is one of the fastest tests to check proper operation of a memory device.

Update in response to comment.

I implemented this specific test to determine the presence or absence of a flash device in the early 1990s, so yes, it works with flash.

[Update for full buffer write]

Some older (and many serial access) devices require that a complete [write buffer](http://www.cypress.com/file/205856/download) be filled; this simply (internally) increments a counter so you can programme the data word using the above algorithm and simply fill the rest of the buffer with 0xFF for every other byte - that way only one word actually gets truly programmed (flash devices are 0xFF on a byte basis when *not* programmed).

Comment: walking ones works for flash too ?

Comment: I disagree. FRAM, EEPROM and flash devices are made using different technologies. For EEPROM and flash devices walking ones/zeros test is destructive.

Comment: @Anonymous why its destructive ?

Comment: Look into typical datasheet, I look into SST39VF-LF one. It says "Endurance: 100,000 Cycles (typical)". After 100,000 cycles (erase or write) manufacturer will no more guarantee its reliable operation. Some flash chips or have 1,000 cycles. Flash chips usually have a kind of self-test mechanism in them when you write data into. You do not need to test it at software level other than just high level ensuring that data you want to be there is actually there.

Comment: Anonymous: given the endurance of a typical device, a one-off test to ensure the device is operational is nothing. It could be done at every power-up without materially changing the effective life of the device.

Comment: what do you mean by a complete buffer ? the link you showed, it doesn't explain it that much. would you please explain it ?

Answer (score 0):

Function of EEPROM and flash is to hold specific data or code. You can use checksum to know if it has correct or corrupt data. Writing to flash too many times will wear it out. Thus you need to ensure that:

- chips are physically present in the board (soldered into their places);
- you may want to have chip programmed one time in full and compare to pattern you program to ensure that chip is not DOA;
- you *may* need to check for proper data using checksum on each power up, and act accordingly (e.g. display message, use other data source etc);
- you will need to check for properly programmed data only after programming.

Answer (score 0):

Flash outwears by individual cells leaking too much of the charge they have been loaded with at programming. This could be due to heat or irradiation or manufacturing flaws.

It's hard to detect those pretty common errors, as when you read the data you notice nothing until it's too late and when you write it, you refresh the charge so you cannot see the leaking either.

In the distant past, best practise was to read out EEPROMS every few years or so and re-write the contents. That wouldn't let you see the leaking but at least the leaks wouldn't lead to data loss.